# The App Get Stuck While Trying To serialize an object in metro app

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm trying to save the animes dictionary in my app which  contains string as key and anime as value but when i use the save function the app just get stuck no exception nothing

here is my Anime.cs Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AnimeTrackerNew
{
    [KnownType(typeof(AnimeTrackerNew.Anime))]
    [DataContractAttribute]
    class Anime:IComparable<Anime>
    {
        private string name;
        private int season;
        private int noe;
        private int lw;
        private Boolean finished;

        public Anime(string name)
            : base()
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Anime(string name,int season, int noe, int lw)
            : base()
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.season = season;
            this.noe = noe;
            this.lw = lw;
            if (lw == noe)
                finished=true;
            else
                finished=false;
        }
       [DataMember]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                this.name = value;
            }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public  int Season
        {
            get
            {
                return season;
            }
            set
            {
                this.season = value;
            }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public int Noe
        {
            get
            {
                return noe;
            }
            set
            {
                this.noe = value;
            }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public int Lw
        {
            get
            {
                return lw;
            }
            set
            {
                this.lw = value;
            }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public  Boolean Finished
        {
            get
            {
                return finished;
            }
            set
            {
                this.finished = value;
            }
        }



        public int CompareTo(Anime other)
        {
            return this.Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

and these are the save functions
            static async public Task Save()
            {
                await Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool.RunAsync((sender) =>
                {
                    Sys.SaveAsync().Wait();
                }, Windows.System.Threading.WorkItemPriority.Normal);
            }

```
        static async public Task Restore<T>()
        {
            await Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool.RunAsync((sender) =>
            {
                Sys.RestoreAsync<T>().Wait();
            }, Windows.System.Threading.WorkItemPriority.Normal);
        }
        static async private Task SaveAsync<T>()
        {


            StorageFile sessionFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("animes.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            IRandomAccessStream sessionRandomAccess = await sessionFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
            IOutputStream sessionOutputStream = sessionRandomAccess.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
            DataContractSerializer sessionSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string,Anime>), new Type[] { typeof(T) });
            sessionSerializer.WriteObject(sessionOutputStream.AsStreamForWrite(), animes);
            await sessionOutputStream.FlushAsync();
            sessionRandomAccess.Dispose();
        }

        static async private Task RestoreAsync<T>()
        {
            StorageFile sessionFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("animes.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            if (sessionFile == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            IInputStream sessionInputStream = await sessionFile.OpenReadAsync();
            DataContractSerializer sessionSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string,Anime>), new Type[] { typeof(T) });
            animes = (Dictionary<string, Anime>)sessionSerializer.ReadObject(sessionInputStream.AsStreamForRead());
        }

    }
}
```

after a little debugging it seems the app get stuck on this line

```
await sessionOutputStream.FlushAsync();
```

any help with this one would be appriciated:D

Comment: Please try to find an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Your exception might get swallowed depending on what thread its thrown on, make sure you're set to break on thrown exceptions in visual studio. You can set this on the debug menu > Exceptions > check `Thrown` on `Common Languange Runtime Exceptions`

Also, you could eliminate the `Save<T>`/`Restore<T>` method and call `SaveAsync<T>`/`RestoreAsync<T>` directly, they are both async anyway so `Save<T>`/`Restore<T>` is a little redundant. It also creates a unnecessary call to the threadpool.

Comment: well it doesn't seem that my exception get swallowed i checked the settings for exceptions and it was alright  about  the save and restore functions you are right i just copied the code from a thread here:)  still when I try to run save functions the app get stuck and now I know it gets stuck on the await sessionOutputStream.FlushAsync line

Comment: Are you able to step though the code to the end as well? if not, atleast you might gain more insight to what call is not returning. in VS2013 they've made the callstacks for async calls a little easier to follow btw :)

Comment: I solved my problem:P I was just doing something stupid when I tried to call save function:P thx anyway:)

Comment: Glad you found the problem :)